# Prevent MySQL Duplicate Insert

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with a auto incremented key. I need a way to only insert into that table if the table does not contain the row I am inserting. INSERT IGNORE and INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE won't work because the auto incremented key will cause the row to always be different. What is another way I can insert the following line only if there is no duplicate row? Thanks.

```
INSERT INTO TableName (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ("value1", "value2", "value3");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a `UNIQUE` constraint on whichever column you need to be unique, or a combination of columns.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `TableName`
ADD UNIQUE `constrain_me` (`column1`, `column2`);
```

If you want to ignore any error a duplicate insert might give, use `INSERT IGNORE`, although you may want to catch this error instead of brushing it under the rug.

Comment: Also I need it so column1 and column2 are unique together. If column1 is different but column 2 is the same then I insert but if column1 and column2 are the same I don't insert.

Comment: This is what the combined key will do. You can specify multiple column names to create a constraint that will not allow the same _combination_ of values. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Unique Indexes on the fields that you don't want duplicated.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MyIndex ON column1
```

This way, if a duplicate value is added, the query will error out.  It's also worth noting that this method does allow NULL values to be added (i.e. two rows with NULL column1 values won't count as duplicates)